# Remote console.log() on iOS devices

Tags: debugging, ios, mobile, safari, webkit

I am developing a web app that involves touchEvent. It will be much more easier to debug those if I can view the console remotely on my Mac.

Can I make my Mobile Safari on the iOS device store the console log somewhere in the system. I have already jailbreak my iPad.

Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

1. plug iphone into computer
2. settings > safari > advanced > web inspector (turn on)
3. open safari on your computer
4. run your web app on your iphone in the safari browser
5. on your computer in safari, go to Develop -> "name of your iphone" and then find the correct tab under "Safari" opens Web Inspector.

doing these steps enables the safari debug tools on your desktop to reflect and respond to the connected iphone.

hope that helps.

Comment: I'm using Safari 13.0.1 and I don't see a "Inspectable Applications" button. What I did see was the name of my phone and only then a list of my open Safari tabs on mobile.

Comment: answer still works, except the last step (Safari 13.1.2) => simply open Safari on your Mac -> Develop -> "name of your iPad" and then find the correct tab under "Safari" opens Web Inspector.

Answer (score 5):

[One File Remote Console.log for node.js](https://github.com/voidfiles/Node.js-Remote-Console.log)

Solution: Server side console log.

Answer (score 5):

Just turn on the debugging console in Mobile Safari. This is enabled in Settings/Safari/Developer.

Comment: He mentions having a jailbreak so can't have iOS6.
Anyway I recommend installing it and using Remote Web Inspector too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a remote javascript console. There a few available.

- [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/)
- [spotneedle](http://spotneedle.com)
- [jsconsole](https://github.com/remy/jsconsole)

Comment: I've used jsconsole; works well still, even in 10/2015.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS6, you can now use the Remote Web Inspector on OSX to connector to the iPhone via USB. See the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm allowed to re-post my answer from another question, but [at this link here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74900302/195835) I posted 3 options of JS console and logging tools that can assist with troubleshooting issues on iOS devices, with screenshots and sample code snippets. One of these is an open source tool I built myself, but the other two are probably even more advanced.

Answer (score -2):

[mobile-console-log](https://github.com/jlguenego/mobile-console-log) is also a utility for debugging directly from your mobile into Chrome Devtools