# .detach().sort().appendTo() does not work on Safari mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following code does not work on Safari mobile:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $("fieldset").each(function() {
        $(this).children(".input").detach().sort(function(a, b) {
            return $(a).attr("data-sort") < $(b).attr("data-sort");
        }).appendTo(this);
    });
});
```

The html looks somewhat like this:

```
<fieldset>
    <span class='input' data-sort='3'><input>.....</input></span>
    <span class='input' data-sort='1'><input>.....</input></span>
    <span class='input' data-sort='2'><input>.....</input></span>
</fieldset>
```

It works just fine on desktop. Any ideas of what's going on?

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console ?

Comment: This might be a noobie problem, but  I can't check the console on mobile. On desktop, no errors.

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478271/remote-console-log-on-ios-devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. The callback function for .sort() was badly designed.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $("fieldset").each(function() {
        $(this).children(".input").detach().sort(function(a, b) {
            var contentA =parseInt( $(a).attr('data-sort'));
            var contentB =parseInt( $(b).attr('data-sort'));
            return (contentA < contentB) ? -1 : (contentA > contentB) ? 1 : 0;
        }).appendTo(this);
    });
});
```